# Deleting data in SQLIte via ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, delete-row

I want to delete a row in my Database via a ListView. I already managed to display the data in a listview. I am working with a OnItemLongClickListener which then opens up a Dialog to delete the clicked item. I can't get the actual delete method to work.

The OnCLickListener method:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) {
            build = new AlertDialog.Builder(ZeigeFaecherListe.this);
            build.setTitle("Fach löschen?" + faecherListe.get(position));
            build.setMessage("Willst du das Fach wirklich löschen?");

            build.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });

            build.setPositiveButton("Löschen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    myDb.loescheFach(position);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), faecherListe.get(position) + " gelöscht.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    myDb.zeigeFaecher();
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();
        return true;
        }
    });
```

The actual delete method:

```
public int loescheFach(int position){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("Fach_table","FACHID=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(position)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing your list position with id, they might not match.

Change your `myDb.loescheFach(position);` to `myDb.loescheFach(id);`

Comment: **id** will be the same value as **position** *(long instead of int though)*. It is only different for a **CursorAdapter** *(the question uses an ArrayAdapter)* when **id** will be the value of the mandatory **_id** column in the Cursor (which should be an alias of the rowid).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the position of ArrayList to SQLite to delete statement. You should pass `FACHID` (in your case) as an argument to delete statement.

As your posted code is incomplete I assume it as below.

```
....
....

build.setPositiveButton("Löschen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               // myDb.loescheFach(position);

               // first get an id from ArrayList using position faecherListe.get(position)

               // then pass that id to your method 
               myDb.loescheFach(id);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), faecherListe.get(position) + " gelöscht.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                myDb.zeigeFaecher();
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });

....
....
```

Comment: When I try to get the id with faecherListe.get(position) I'm getting an error that it's only finding a String. But how do I get the actual ID?

Comment: I guess you have ArrayList of String, that's why are getting String value from ArrayList

Comment: Ye, do you maybe have any Idea how i can delete using the ID gut without displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

First **position** will not equate to the **rowid**/**id** of the row in the table. Assuming that you have a **id** column defined as `your_id_column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` *(or with the AUTOINCREMENT keyword, that makes no real difference)* and that you don't specify a value when inserting a row then the first **id** will likely be 1, then 2 then 3 ... etc.

However, **position** (3rd parameter passed to onItemClick/onItemLongClick) for the first item in the List will be 0, then 1 then 2 etc. So you will never actually delete correct row (clicking the first item will delete nothing, clicking the second item will delete the first) and when rows are deleted it gets even more out of sync.

The 4th parameter (**long id**) passed will be the **rowid**/id IF AND ONLY IF a CursorAdapter is used (i.e. a Cursor is the source data for the ListView). In which case the cursor MUST have a column named **_id**. However, it looks as though **`faecherListe`** is the source and as you use the **`get`** method that it is an ArrayList/List. As such the **id** passed will be the same value **position** except it is a long.

Now if **`faecherListe`** were an `ArrayList<object_that_reflects_the_columns_of_the_table_including_id>` then assuming a getter of getId you could use  `long retrieved_id = faecherListe.get(position).getId()`. However, the comments :-

> I guess you have ArrayList of String, that's why are getting String
>   value from ArrayList – *Shashanth 10 hours ago*
>
> Ye

You simply have ArrayList and thus no means of ascertaining the id unless whatever data is held by the String is guaranteed to be unique.

#### Example

This is an example using  *`object_that_reflects_the_columns_of_the_table_including_id`* in this case a **`Feacher`** class that just has a **name** and an **id**

#### Feacher.java

This is an entirely new class that allows you to have an ArrayList with all the relevant data/fields/columns (especially the **id** column). 
i.e. you can an have ArrayList

```
public class Feacher {

    private String name;
    private long id;

    public Feacher(String feacher_name) {
        this(feacher_name,-1);
    }

    public Feacher(String feacher_name, long feacher_id) {
        this.name = feacher_name;
        this.id = feacher_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " ID(" + String.valueOf(id) + ")";
    }
}
```

#### DBHelper

This is the database helper (sub class of SQLiteOpenHelper) :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "feacher.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_FEACHER = "feacher";
    public static final String COL_FEACHER_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_FEACHER_NAME = "feacher_name";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_FEACHER +
                "(" +
                COL_FEACHER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_FEACHER_NAME + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addFeacher(String feacher_name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_FEACHER_NAME,feacher_name);
        return mDB.insert(TB_FEACHER,null,cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<Feacher> getAllAsFeacherArrayList() {
        ArrayList<Feacher> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(
                TB_FEACHER,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(new Feacher(
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_FEACHER_NAME)),
                    csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_FEACHER_ID))
                    )
            );
        }
        return rv;
    }

    public int deleteFeacher(long id) {
        return mDB.delete(
                TB_FEACHER,
                COL_FEACHER_ID + "=?"
                ,new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}
                );
    }
}
```

- the `deleteFeacher` method to delete a row according to it's **id**,
- the `addFeacher` method allowing some test data to be added.
- the `getAllAsFeacherArrayList` returns all data as an ArrayList (note uses the constructor that sets the **id**)

#### MainActivity.java

The activity that has the ListView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mListView;
    ArrayAdapter<Feacher> mAdapter;
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    ArrayList<Feacher> mFeacherList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        addDataForTesting();
        displayAdapter();
    }

    private void displayAdapter() {
        if (mFeacherList == null) {
            mFeacherList = mDBHlpr.getAllAsFeacherArrayList();
        } else {
            mFeacherList.clear();
            for (Feacher f: mDBHlpr.getAllAsFeacherArrayList()) {
                mFeacherList.add(f);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Feacher>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mFeacherList);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                     mDBHlpr.deleteFeacher(mAdapter.getItem(i).getId());
                     displayAdapter();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void addDataForTesting() {
        mDBHlpr.addFeacher("Feacher 001");
        mDBHlpr.addFeacher("Feacher 002");
        mDBHlpr.addFeacher("Feacher 003");
    }
}
```

- Note for simplicity and also to avoid inadvertent deletion `onItemLongClick` has been used. The all important bit being  `mDBHlpr.deleteFeacher(mAdapter.getItem(i).getId());` which gets the id from the item (object, the Feacher) that was clicked according to the position.

#### activity_main.xml

A very basic layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFAAAAFF"
        >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Result

here's a screen shot after 3rd run so 9 rows have been added and 2 rows have been deleted (note id's 2 and 5 are missing). The list will refresh after a deletion so the row disappears almost immediately the long-click is completed.

[image]